# attaching JS functions to dynamically created object events

Tags: javascript

I use following code to dynamically add rows to my ASP.NET table. I create a span, then fill it with an html textbox code to create some textboxes in my row, now I'm going to attach some functions to my textbox events, for instant blur or keypress event:

```
            var TR = document.createElement('tr');
        TR.style.textAlign = 'center';

        //mission end date
        var TD = document.createElement('td');
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "<input maxlength='5' type='text' width='50px' style='width:50px;' value=''/>";
        TD.appendChild(span);
        TR.appendChild(TD);
.......
        TR.appendChild(TD);
        document.getElementById('<%=tblData.ClientID %>').appendChild(TR);
```

I've create some other javascript functions that I'd like to attach them to these dynamically created textbox events, for instance:

```
function onBlur(){
.....
}
```

how can I attach onBlur to onblur event of these dynamically created objects?
thanks

Comment: Easiest would probably be to use jQuery and its event delegation method `on`.

Comment: can I user JQuery here? isn't it possible with javascript?

Comment: or use `var myInput = document.createElement("input"); myInput.addEventListener(...); mySpan.appendChild(myInput);`

Comment: You can do it with Javascript, it's just more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
  span.innerHTML = "<input maxlength='5' type='text' width='50px' style='width:50px;' value=''/>";
```

with

```
 var input = document.createElement("input");
 input.style.width="50px";
 input.type="text";
 input.onblur = your_function_handler;
 span.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: it worked thanks, but there is another problem, I must pass input object ID to my handler function, and then I use getElementById in this function to work on this dynamically created object, but it says object is null, what is going wrong?

Comment: you can add any data to dataAttributes. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/KdMWJ/ ; also i assume that i didn't fully understand your task, and you can use any other way to pass data to functions.